# Moving Yii2 application to live server

Tags: yii2

I've moved my Yii2 application from localhost to live server in the following location

```
www.mydoamin.com/awpet
```

awpet is the subdomain where the application will run.
Also, I've put the following code in the awpet directory as index.php

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
?>
```

Now when I'm going to awpet.mydomain.com I'm getting the following error - 
[image]

The asset directory is not present in the `awpet` folder. And I'm not sure where it'll come from... I already have asset directory in `awpet/frontend/web` folder.

I can access awpet.mydomain.com/frontend/web/index.php.

awpet/frontend/config/main.php

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'name'=>'My AWPET',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'gridview' =>  [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'
        ],
        'workpermit' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\modules\workpermit\workpermit',
        ],
    ],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],

        // 'urlManager' => [
        //     'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        //     'showScriptName' => false,
        //     'rules' => [
        //     ],
        // ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your changes from index.php.
Open frontend/config/main.php.
Pay attention to the line `'baseUrl' => '',` comment out it.
Use:`'scriptUrl' => @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' ? '/index.php' : '/awpet/index.php'`

Ok. My version separation on frontend and backend.

.htaccess on root of the project

```
    # Mod_Autoindex
    <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    # Mod_Rewrite
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    IndexIgnore */*

    # Open access to storage directory
    RewriteRule ^(admin/)?storage/(.+)$ storage/$2 [L,PT]
    RewriteRule ^admin/?([^/].*)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
    RewriteRule ^([^/].*)?$ frontend/web/$1
    </IfModule>
```

.htacces on frontend/web

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

.htaccess on backend/web

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

frontend/config/main.php

```
    'request' => [
        'scriptUrl' => @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' ? '/index.php' : '/awpet/index.php',
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
```

backend/config/main.php

```
    'request' => [
        'scriptUrl' => @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' ? '/admin/index.php' : '/awpet/admin/index.php',
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
    ],
```

Comment: Hi valerii, I don't have 'baseUrl' => '', in main.php. I've given the code of frontend/config/main.php in the question. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can read, does your subdomain awpet.mydomain.com points to *www.mydoamin.com*/awpet;

but shouldn't it be pointing at *www.mydoamin.com*/awpet/frontend/web ?

*www.mydoamin.com* ... should be the servers path; eg.: /root/www/html/..